# Unknown amount of UILabels inside of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've created a `UITableViewCell` in the Interface Builder and created a subclass for it. Inside it I need to display raffle results in labels. I don't know how many results I'm going to get so I can't create labels for it in the IB so I'm creating them inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. So what is happening right now that I keep creating subviews over subviews when the cell is reused.

I thought about creating the labels in the Interface Builder \ `awakeFromNib` of the Cell subclass and them fill them using their tag but I don't know how many labels are going to be.

What's a good way to solve it?

**Is there a way to remove to content of the cell once it's out of the screen region?**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Where we configure the cell in each row
    id currentRaffle = [_winnings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    RaffleResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RaffleResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];
    }
    cell.prizeTitle.text = [currentRaffle valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSArray *winningNumbers = [[currentRaffle valueForKey:@"winningNumbers"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    cell.numbOfRowsPerCell = 1+ [winningNumbers count]/4;
    int row =0;
    int col=0;
    for (int i=0;i<[winningNumbers count];i++)
    {
        UILabel *temp =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70*row, 30*col, 70, 20)];
        temp.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        temp.font=[temp.font fontWithSize:14];
        temp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  ",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];
        [cell.winningNumbersView addSubview:temp];
        if(row<3)
        [cell.winningNumbersView addSubview:line];
        row++;
        if(row >3)
        {
            row=0;
            col++;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In answer to "Is there a way to remove to content of the cell once it's out of the screen region?", no. Because once a cell is out the screen region, it no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding subviews to the cell instead of using the default label, you need to remove the subviews that already have the cell with something like this:

```
while (cell.subviews.count != 0)
{
    [[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
// And then, add the new subviews
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Let me see if I understood it correctly. Basically what will happen is ,at the beginning of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I will check if the cell already have subviews. If it does, the `while` will empty it so it would be ready for new content?

Comment: Exact! i often use this solution because I normally add custom views to my tableviewcells

Comment: I think it's the only way of removing the old content(subviews) if u want to add new subviews. But maybe you need another approach for creating the labels.

Comment: If i'm removing the subviews each time from the super view I think it solves the memory problem so I really don't know why there should be anything wrong with that approach.

Comment: I agree, this solution works in your case and should be accepted.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution, you are removing ALL the subviews, some of which may not need removing, and you defeat the purpose of cell reusue.  My solution accounts for only removing the dynamically created labels.

Comment: I changed Javito original code to something like cell.someView.subview . Vote up to your answer too Tim. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the `UILabels` every time, regardless of reuse.  You need to add the `UILabels` at cell creation only.

This requires a slightly more elegant solution though if the number of labels each time will vary.

Perhaps add a single `UIView` container in `IB`, that will hold all of your dynamically created `UILabels`, and remove all the `UILabels` each time.

e.g.

```
for (UILabel *label in cell.labelContainer.subviews) {
    [label removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in this kind of approch that everytime the cell is loaded the labels will be added above and above over and over again in the cell,wheenever `cellForrowAtIndexpath:` is called.To avoid that creation and addition of `UILabel` ***must*** be done in the if(cell==nil) section

Comment: I can't use cell=nil in a storyBoard prototype UITableViewCell. It will never be accessed.

Comment: Then dont use storyboard prototype here or drive a new logic to make allocated only a single time